# Parse table <td> from remote HTML with BS4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I m new to python (3), and I would like to parse an HTML page. I use BS4, and would like to parse, for instance, this page: http://www.myfxbook.com/members/fxgrowthbot/forex-growth-bot/71611

I am only interested in the

```
<div id="history"  style="display:none" >
```

table and its related < td > tags.

Here is what I have. I do not know how I can iterate over all < td > in the table.

```
import urllib.request
from html.parser import HTMLParser

url_to_parse = 'http://www.myfxbook.com/members/fxgrowthbot/forex-growth-bot/71611'

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
print( 'Requesting URL ' + url_to_parse + '...')
response = urllib.request.urlopen( url_to_parse )
print('Done')

print( 'Reading URL ' + url_to_parse + '...')
html = response.read()
print('Done')

soup = BeautifulSoup( str(html) )

print( '*** History ***')
for h in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"id" : "history"}):
print( 'Found Historyy <div>!')

history = soup.select("#history")
# How to iterate over history table's td?
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: What about `history = soup.select("#history").find_all("td")`?

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. This did not do the trick. Instead, I had to use: `history = soup.select("#history")` and then `history_tds = history[0].find_all("td", recursive=True)`.
However, it only gives me acces to the first < td > and not the others (whatever the value of the `recursive` parameter is). Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you do it:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url_to_parse = 'http://www.myfxbook.com/members/fxgrowthbot/forex-growth-bot/71611'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_to_parse)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
a = soup.find(id='history').find_all('td')

print(len(a))  # 300
```

Comment: As I told in my previous comment, this only gives me access to the first < td > (I just tried with your new solution). How can I access the others?

Comment: Benjamin, you are right, I made a mistake. Several < td >'s are diaplayed, but only the ones of the first row. So, did you manage to grab **all** < td >'s of the table?
The XPath (got it from chrome) for the first row of data is `//*[@id="tradingHistoryTable"]/tbody/tr[2]` and `//*[@id="tradingHistoryTable"]/tbody/tr[4]` for the second row of data.
Could you please confirm that with your code you only get the < td >'s of the first row?

Comment: How is it possible?? I use python 3.3.3 and BS 4.3.2, windows 64bits. What about you?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code I use which only return me the < td >'s of the first row:
    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
url_to_parse = 'http://www.myfxbook.com/members/autotrade/wallstreet-forex-robot-real/95290'

print( 'Requesting URL ' + url_to_parse + '...')
response = urllib.request.urlopen( url_to_parse )
print('Done')

print( 'Reading URL ' + url_to_parse + '...')
html = response.read()
print('Done')

soup = BeautifulSoup( str(html) )

history_td = soup.find(id='history').find_all('td')
for td in history_td:
    print(td)
```

Comment: Is it me or did you just copy my answer?

Comment: @BenjaminToueg Yes, I did. So, do not understand why I only get the < td >'s of the first row, and you, got 300+ < td > ...

Comment: I've updated my answer with full script, let me know. You do not need to use `str(html)`, just `html`. That's where the problem lies.